# This Sobolev function is continuous?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset R^n $  $(n \geq 2) $ an open bounded domain with smooth boundary $u \in W^{ 1,p}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ ($p \geq 2$ fixed). Suppose that exist $M > 0$ such that

$$ \int_B |\nabla u| \ dx \leq Mr$$ for all ball $B \subset \Omega,$
where $r$ is the radius of the ball $B.$

From this can I say that $u$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $r$? Is it the radius of the ball $B$?

Comment: yes. you re right. I will fix this. thanks

Comment: For any $0<a\leq n-2$ we have that $\sin(|x|^{-a})$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: The previous example shows that this fails for $p<n$. For $p>n$ the continuity follows from Morrey's inequality. Therefore only the $p=n$ case remains.